# Bivariate Gaussian Variables: Finding the distribution of the conditional probability

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, bivariate-distributions

Exercise question (from Timo Koski's book *Lecture Notes: Probability and Random Processes at KTH*):

---

Let $(X_{1},X_{2})'\in N(\pmb{\mu},\pmb{C})$, where

$$\pmb{\mu}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$\pmb{C}=\begin{pmatrix}
 1&\rho \\ 
 \rho&1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

a) We want to find the distribution of the random variable $X_{1}|X_{2}\leq a$. Show that

$$\pmb{P}(X_{1}\leq x|X_{2}\leq a)=\frac{1}{\Phi(a)}\int_{-\infty}^{x}\phi(u)\Phi\left(\frac{a-\rho u}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\right)du,$$

where $\Phi(x)$ is the distribution function of $N(0,1)$ and $\phi(x)$ the p.d.f. (probability density function) od $N(0,1)$, i.e., $\frac{d}{dx}\Phi(x)=\phi(x)$. We sketch two different solutions.

*Aid* 1. We need to find

$$\pmb{P}(X_{1}\leq a|X_{2}\leq a)=\frac{\pmb{P}(\{X_{1}\leq x\}\cap \{X_{2}\leq a\})}{\pmb{P}(X_{2}\leq a)}.$$

Then

$$\pmb{P}(\{X_{1}\leq x\}\cap \{X_{2}\leq a\})=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\int_{-\infty}^{a}f_{X_{1},X_{2}}(u,v)dudv=\\
=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_{X_{2}}(v)\int_{-\infty}^{a}f_{X_{1}|X_{2}=v}(u)dudv.$$

Now find $f_{X_{2}}(v)$ and $f_{X_{1}|X_{2}=v}(u)$ and make a change of variable in $\int_{-\infty}^{a}f_{X_{1}|X_{2}=v}(u)du$.

*Aid* 2. Write $(X_{1},X_{2})'$ as a linear transformation of the standard Gaussian vector $\pmb{Z}=(Z_{1},Z_{2})'\in N(\pmb{0},\pmb{I})$ as

$$\begin{pmatrix}
X_{1}\\ 
X_{2}
\end{pmatrix}=\pmb{B}
\begin{pmatrix}
Z_{1}\\ 
Z_{2}
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Here we have

$$\pmb{B}=\begin{pmatrix}
 \sigma_{1}&0 \\ 
 \sigma_{2}\rho& \sigma_{2}\sqrt{1-\rho^2}
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Then you can, since $\pmb{B}$ is invertible, write the event

$$\{X_{1}\leq x\}\cap \{X_{2}\leq a\}$$

as an event using (the innovations) $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ and then compute the desired probability using the joint distribution of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$.

---

Now, these aids don't help me that much and I'm in no better position to solve this problem. How am I supposed to go about it? I did try writing out the $X_1$ and $X_2$ and inserting the innovations into the event, but from there I do not know what to do. My intuition tells me nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proceed with your first method.

Simply use the law of total probability for the joint CDF of $(X_1,X_2)$:

\begin{align}
P(X_1\le x,X_2\le a)&=\int_{-\infty}^x P(X_2\le a\mid X_1=u)f_{X_1}(u)\,du
\\&=\int_{-\infty}^x \Phi\left(\frac{a-\rho u}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\right)\phi(u)\,du\quad,
\end{align}

where we have used that $X_2$ given $X_1=u$ has a $N(\rho u,1-\rho^2)$ distribution, and of course $X_1\sim N(0,1)$.

Comment: Alright, thank you! I think I understand. Did you miss an integral sign at the second expression? Since we know the distribution of X_2 given X_1, and also that of X_1, we just replace it with the c.d.f. (that is big Phi), and the argument becomes accordingly. But you had to switch places of the arguments in the conditional probability? Isn't that unnecessary, or am I missing something?

Comment: @SimpleProgrammer 

\begin{align}
P(X_1\le x,X_2\le a)&=\iint_{u\le x,v\le a} f_{X_1,X_2}(u,v)\,du\,dv
\\&=\int_{-\infty}^a\int_{-\infty}^x f_{X_2\mid X_1=u}(v)f_{X_1}(u)\,du\,dv
\\&=\int_{-\infty}^x\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^a f_{X_2\mid X_1=u}(v)\,dv}_{P(X_2\le a\mid X_1=u)}\,f_{X_1}(u)\,du
\end{align}

You can interchange the order of integration by [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem).

Comment: One can do a similar thing using $f_{X_1\mid X_2}$ also. I used $f_{X_2\mid X_1}$ to match the given answer.